# PHP - Get 3 latest value from DB

Tags: php, database

How do I get the 3 latest values from the database.
My codes to show all values is like this :

```
<?php
    $query="select hari from reg";
    $hasil=mysql_query($query);
?>
<table  style="text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
    </tr>
<?php    
    if($hasil === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }

    while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
        echo ("<tr><td> $data[hari] </td></tr>");
    }
?>
</table>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with php or html.  Its strictly SQL-related

Comment: @danronmoon Surely it is a SQL related question. According to the knwoledge level of the questioner, it's likely he wants an example in PHP as his working environment is PHP...

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="select id , hari from reg ORDERBY id desc LIMIT 3";
```

This will get you the latest 3 records.

Comment: Hi Mostafa, How to assign avg value of 3 latest record to a variable? thanks

Comment: '$query="select id , AVG(hari) ,hari from reg ORDERBY id desc LIMIT 3";'

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="select hari from reg ORDER BY hari DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: thanks hex4. from 3 value printed, i need to count the average, how to sum each value?

Comment: $query="select AVG(hari) from reg ORDER BY hari DESC LIMIT 3";

Comment: i have try the code, but the result seems the average not from 3 latest value? your code count average from all field. how to assign avg value of 3 latest record to a variable? thanks hex4

Comment: you're right sorry. `select AVG(hari) from (SELECT hari  FROM reg ORDER BY hari DESC LIMIT 3) reg_tmp`. You can always loop the result of the original query and average it using PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= SELECT hari FROM reg ORDER BY hari DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use mysqli or PDO_extension --> http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Then like all other's recommendation it's possible with ORDER BY and LIMIT 3.

If you would use timestamps per record you could ORDER BY timestamp and LIMIT 3 to them OR if you use an autoincrement int ORDER BY id and LIMIT 3

Mysql also has functions that can return the last entry.. Maybe there is a function to get a specific amount of last entries.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,hari FROM reg ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3") or die(mysql_error());
```